# Can not add view to any controller in mvc 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql, asp.net-mvc-5

Hello everyone We have searched this error beforehand, but nothing seemed to be our case, since all of the problems that were mentioned were because of using EF Code first, that we are not using it.
After migrating to MVC5, we ran into a problem. Whenever we want to add a view to our controller, we get the following error:

> there was an error running the selected code generator value cannot be null

BTW, we are using LINQ to SQL,and we are not scaffolding the view.
We have left the Template Empty(Without model), and we are not using layout page.
Our project is using ASPX view engine. We had no problem in VS 2012. After migrating to VS 2015 we are running into this problem.
Has ASPX view engine been removed from VS 2015. Could it be the problem?
Any kind of help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Does the error mention a specific line to look at?

Comment: @EthanFischer Thanks for your comment.Actually, no. Sometimes the error text turns to "Value does not fall within the expected range" Without any further information.

Comment: show your controller code

Comment: show your entire error

Comment: @anand This Is our entire error Text: "there was an error running the selected code generator.value cannot be null". Sometimes it turns to "there was an error running the selected code generator.Value does not fall within the expected range"

Comment: BTW, we are using ASPX view engine in VS 2015. Is this the cause of the problem?

Comment: left click the controller and click add view. and check the view page name equal  the contoller name

Comment: @anand Thanks for your comment. It works in a brand new project in the same way.

Comment: @anand It works in VS 2012, but in VS 2015 we still have this problem. We are using ASPX view engine. Do you think that migrating to VS 2015 is cause of this problem?

Comment: by doing the my above steps only cshtml file will be created

Comment: @anand Thanks for your answer. Yes That's it, but we need to add aspx files. Also, it doesn't recognize our MasterPages, since they are aspx files.

Comment: "It works in VS2012" : Which version of .Net Framework and MVC?.. "It doesn't work in VS2015" : Which version of .Net Framework?.. "It works in a new project"... create a new project and compare the web.config files.

Comment: @PaulZahra In VS 2012 we were using .Net Framework 4 along with MVC4, and in VS 2015 we are using .Net Framework 4.5 along with MVC5.

Answer (score 2):

If Prompt for

> there was an error running the selected code generator values does
>   not fall selected range in visual studio

`web.config` has been deleted or renamed.
Please check your `web.config` file. Might be there were any additional tag would be added.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by doing the below method
All I had to do is install [Web Essentials 2015.1](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/ee6e6d8c-c837-41fb-886a-6b50ae2d06a2/view/Reviews) , restarted Visual Studio, repeated the Add View action, and it worked, don't have an explanation to this, but it worked.

Comment: Many thanks for your answers, but not yet. We are checking that whether we can use your solution or not. As soon as it solved our problem we would accept your solution as our answer. Thanks again